# Problem in getting location updates periodically

Tags: android, geolocation

I am using the Location Manager to get location updates. I used Location Manager's RequestLocationUpdates(provider,timeinmilliseconds,distanceinmeters,listener).

When do i provide minimum delay of 30 seconds to get next location updates, i assume that it should rest for 30 seconds to request for new location updates.But what i observed,it is not happening.

I tried specifying minimum distance too, still didn't get what i expected.

What i want is to get location updates after every 10 MINUTES or after moving a distance of 100 meters periodically. But i don't want to use any Timer thread or do any calculation to be sure that i have moved by a distance of 100 meters.

Is it possible to get this thing using location manager only?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you be more specific by what you mean with "But what i observed,it is not happening."?

Comment: are u using map?? can you plz paste your code

Comment: @WarrenFaith : "But what i observed,it is not happening."This means i am not getting updates after specified interval of times.Instead i am getting continuous updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When do i provide minimum delay of 30 seconds to get next location updates, i assume that it should rest for 30 seconds to request for new location updates.

That is a flawed assumption.

> But what i observed,it is not happening.

Correct. The time period you specify is merely a hint. The distance you specify should serve as a filter.

> What i want is to get location updates after every 10 MINUTES or after moving a distance of 100 meters periodically.

OK.

> But i don't want to use any Timer thread or do any calculation to be sure that i have moved by a distance of 100 meters.

You are going to need something to let you know when 10 minutes has elapsed.

> Is it possible to get this thing using location manager only?

No, sorry.

Comment: Okay now i got the clear idea that i have to do some manual calculations to get location updates after every 100 meters.(And In order to get location updates after a periodic interval of time, i can use the timer thread, Right?).but At the same time i want to conserve my battery as much as possible and still want to get updates after every 100 meters. What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: @AndoAiron: "now i got the clear idea that i have to do some manual calculations to get location updates after every 100 meters" -- no, just specify a time of `0` and a distance of `100`. "And In order to get location updates after a periodic interval of time, i can use the timer thread, Right?" -- you use something. What the "something" is depends upon what it is that you're building. "At the same time i want to conserve my battery as much as possible and still want to get updates after every 100 meters." -- those are mutually contradictory goals.

Comment: @AndoAiron: "What would be the best way to achieve this ?" -- there is only one way to achieve it. Register for location updates with a `100` meter filter and a `0` millisecond filter. This will keep the GPS on all of the time, draining battery. Use some timing mechanism to ensure that, if you received no location in 10 minutes, you call `getLastKnownLocation()`. For all that to work you will need to use a `WakeLock` or `android:keepScreenOn`, further draining battery. Or, redesign your app.